# can I create variable in trigger of sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, datatrigger, sqliteopenhelper

I want  to create  a update trigger,

can  I   create a  variable betweent  "BEGIN" and  "END" , and set value  by query  from   a select sql statement ??
 And  then  execute  "if" "else" statement  by judging  this  variable

Comment: What exactly do you want to do in the trigger?

Answer (score 4):

As an embedded database, SQLite is designed to be used directly from another programming language, so it does not have programming constructs like variables or `IF` statements.

If it is not possible to implement your logic with the trigger's `WHEN` clause or subqueries, you have to do this in Java (i.e., without a trigger).

Answer (score 0):

you can create temporary tables with a single row instead of variables, and cross join with them in the rest of the trigger statements, using `where` clauses instead of `if` statements